# Dell XPS 15z Overheats When Using Optirun

Tags: 12.10, games, overheating, bumblebee

I installed Bumblebee on my Dell XPS 15z running Ubuntu 12.10. Now whenever I use optirun to play a game like Minecraft my laptop gets really hot and crashes in about 5 minutes. What can I do to make it not overheat?

I am asking how to somehow limit optirun so it doesn't overheat and shut off the computer. Getting hot is fine as long as it doesn't crash. I don't know if this is possible but I need a way to play games like minecraft using optirun without my laptop overheating.

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent your laptop from overheating or how to make it not get so hot?

Comment: How to prevent it from overheating.

Answer (score 1):

most probably installing the correct VGA driver can reduce overheating. To install correct VGA driver

#### you need to do some simple things if your using ubuntu 12.10

1. first go to software center and type drivers.
2. in there find additional drivers. and install it.
3. after installation complete open it. it will search drivers for your VGA card. **warning! do not close it. because additional drivers not working properly in 12.10 so once you close you cannot find it anywhere. then you must remove it and re-install it again through software center.**
4. install all available VGA drivers for your machine.
5. after installation complete it will ask you to restart. you done!.
6. after restart go to Settings >  Details there you can see your VGA name and type.

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer in more than one place. When tempted to do so, this means that either: (1) the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), or (3) the answer should really be a comment, (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.